# zookeeper and HBase OR HBase including ZooKeeper

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hbase, ubuntu-14.04, apache-zookeeper

I configured a multi node hadoop env on AWS (1 master/3 slaves running on Ubuntu 14.04). now I am planning to install and configure other Apache bricks (not sure which one exactly yet). I decided to start with HBase.

**here is my dilemma:** should I install zookeeper as a standalone and then HBase (taking into consideration future bricks like pig, hive ...) or should I use zookeeper/Hbase bundled?
How this choices may affect subsequent architecture design ?

thanks for sharing your views/personal experiences !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really matter all that much from a capabilities point of view.  If you install the bundled HBase+ZK, you'll still be able to use ZK later on to support other bricks.  Since installing the bundle is likely to be the quickest path to a working HBase, it is probably the best option for you.

Answer (score 0):

ZK ensemble is recommended to be run on separate machines (Odd number), in any production environment.

For your learning & experimenting, it can co-exist in one machine.

More information @ https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.2/zookeeperAdmin.html